# Prestashop database update with db class

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

I am a newbie in Prestashop. I am doing a small module. In that module I want to update a table. But my condition is like this it will update those rows whose id is not 3. So for me my table is like this

```
id      name        active
1       test1       0
2       test4       0
3       test5       1
4       test9       0
5       test12      0
6       test25      0
```

So as per [DB classes](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/DB+class+best+practices#DBclassbestpractices-update()) I made my query like this

```
$id = 3;
Db::getInstance()->update('table', array('active'=>'1'), 'id != '.$id );
```

also I have tried

```
Db::getInstance()->update('table', array('active'=>'1'), 'id <> '.$id );
```

But its not working. So can someone kindly tell me how to fix this.
Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable.

Comment: Have you turned of DEV mode? What are the errors?

Comment: I am not getting any errors

Comment: is status column integer or varchar ? because if its varchar, the operator may be wrong

Comment: @gskema check my updated question. The active column is in tinyint.

Comment: Hmm do you know that first argument - table name get automatically prefixed with _DB_PREFIX_ ? So in your case the final table name would be ps_table.

Comment: Yes I know that. There is no problem in the table name

Comment: I just tested and it works fine `Db::getInstance()->update('table', array('active' => 1), 'id_table != '.(int)$id);` - maybe you should try using integer values for insertion and id; also try renaming id column ?

Answer (score 3):

The solution, as gskema states, is to cast the ID to int:

```
Db::getInstance()->update('table', array('active'=>'1'), 'id != '.(int)$id );
```

PrestaShop needs you to pass the appropriate type of value for each column. For the "decimal" type, nevertheless, you can pass in a string, if the value is in the correct format.